# Arduino taking forever to upload sketch

Tags: arduino

I am using Arduino Uno board and programming it with a Windows 10 system. From the tutorials on Arduino website, I am trying to upload the following code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(1);
}
```

It had undergone a series of issues:

First,
`avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\com3"`

I searched for his issue, and found that most common solution is to go to device manager and change the name of the port, then unplug and plug again the arduino board. I did that

Second,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\axr\bin\avr-ar:
unable to rename 'core.a'; reason: file exists\\
```

I thought it could be a memory problem. I used the reset button on the board, and repeated steps from the solution to the first problem. I tried to upload the code again.

But now, I am not getting any error message. But the problem is that it is taking forever to upload the code. I see `Uploading...` status since a long while. The green progress bar is also complete, but no uploading completed till now.

Any help to understand and solve this will be appreciated.

Comment: Some simple steps to check for an easy solution: Close Arduino IDE, unplug Arduino USB cable, reopen Arduino IDE, check Serial Port (under tools), plug in USB, check Serial Port again to see which COM port appears. Select the COM port which just appeared.

Comment: @Calum, thanks! tried that, Its still the same, no improvements!

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to disable Apple's Bonjour service with the task manager.